# I'm migrating my JSX site to TSX and don't understand how to place my type definitions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, google-maps-react

Just like the title says I am migrating an app that I created that uses the Google Maps API to render the map and from there I show some information on maps and have some function to pan in if the user clicks something.

the error code that I am getting is this.

> Type '{ lat: () => number; lng: () => number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'LatLng': equals, toJSON, toUrlValue

This is the code that is generating the error.

```
  const {
    ready,
    value,
    suggestions: { status, data },
    setValue,
    clearSuggestions,
  } = usePlacesAutocomplete({
    requestOptions: {
      location: { lat: () => 40.7703, lng: () => -73.9883 }, // This line specifically
      radius: 50 * 1000,
    },
  });
```

This is the panTo function that search is taking into account.

```
const panTo = React.useCallback(({ lat, lng }) => {
    mapRef.current.panTo({ lat, lng });
    mapRef.current.setZoom(14);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Did you try following what the error says and adding those properties that it says is required to that object?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have and I still get the error... I am not sure if the format of my data could be the reason because is not a json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation for the [AutocompletionRequest interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service#AutocompletionRequest) used by `requestOptions`. The `location` property is required to be an instance of [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng)

```ts
usePlacesAutocomplete({
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7703, -73.9883),
  radius: 50 * 1000,
});
```

Comment: Thank you! for the snippet and for pointing me to the documentation it helped solved it!